# Can any one give me a hint how to get the spot_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a car park booking application and general booking works. When I type in `user id`, `spot id` and select `is_booked`.
Now I would like the button next to the list of spots to work the same way, but I can't get the id of the spot, like this:

```
    <% @spots.each do |spot| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= spot.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', spot %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_spot_path(spot) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Booking', new_booking_path %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

The path at the moment is to new_booking but only for preview,eventually it will be create_booking.

I've tried several ways but none works, I am able to reference all ids but not a single id. This one is sample from booking_controller to new_booking definition and I give these parameters:

`@booking = current_user.bookings.build(:spot_id => Spot.ids, :is_booked => true)`

I hope I've described the problem clearly. I'm fairly new to ruby and this seems to be a trivial error that I don't know how to fix. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails way to solve this is by creating a [nested route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resources :spots do
  resources :bookings, shallow: true
end
```

This will create the path `/spots/:spot_id/bookings` which means that the spot id is passed as part of the URL.

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationRecord
  before_action :set_spot, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  before_action :set_booking, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /spots/1/bookings/new
  def new
    @booking = @spot.bookings.new
  end

  # POST /spots/1/bookings
  def create
    @booking = @spot.bookings.new(booking_params) do |b|
      b.user = current_user
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: "Booking was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def set_spot
    @spot = Spot.find(params[:spot_id])
  end

  def set_booking
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking)
          .permit(:starts_at)
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/bookings/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form' %>
```

```
# app/views/bookings/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: [@spot, @booking]) |form| %>
  # ...
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you max, you found my mistake regarding routing.
Now the correct URL is created but I have a problem with the new and create methods for bookings...
```undefined method `bookings' for #<Spot id: 28, name: ```

Comment: You need to add `has_many :bookings` to your `Spot` model. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: If it solves your probelm you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to nest the resource in your /config/routes.rb file.

so that relationship will look like this:

```
resources :spots do
  resources :bookings
end
```

After doing that, if you run rails routes from the command line you will now see a new route `new_spot_booking_path`, and you can use it in your template as new_spot_booking_path(spot).

Take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources  and routing in general

Good luck!